# How to get bullets to work properly in glidejs

Tags: javascript, html, glidejs

I'm trying to use glidejs as the slider on a website, however I can't get the bullets to work properly. The bullets are at the bottom of the example on glidejs' website on this page: https://glidejs.com/docs/options/ On my site, the bullets show up, but clicking on them does not change the slide. I haven't found any documentation for options that need to be passed in the initialization of glidejs to make these work. As far as I can tell from the glidejs site, initializing glide should make this work automatically. Everything else I have done works as expected, such as having the slides change on a timer and also having the arrow navigation for next and previous slides. I have the init code in a file called glideInit.js that looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var glide = new Glide('#slider', {
        type : 'carousel',
        perView : 1,
        focusAt : 'center',
        breakpoints : {
            800 : {
                perView : 1
            },
            480 : {
                perView : 1
            }
        },
        autoplay: 5000
    });

    glide.mount();

});

function startTimer() {
    setInterval(function() {
        forward('slideForward');
    }, 5000);
}
```

Here is the html I have for the slider:

```
<div id="slider" class="glide">
        <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
            <div class="glide__slides">
                {% for entry in entries %}
                {% set url = entry.slideBackgroundImage.first().getUrl() %}

                <div class="hero -homepage glide__slide">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1 class="hero__title -homepage"><a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="title-link">{{ entry.title }}</a></h1>

                        <div class="hero__row">
                            <div class="override-redactor">
                                <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.slideExcerpt }}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
            <button id="slideBack" class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">&lt;</button>
            <button id="slideForward" class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">&gt;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="glide__bullets" data-guide-el="controls[nav]">
            <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=0"></button>
            <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=1"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I have implemented it using with `react` https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560980/5124488

Answer (score 5):

It might be old but there is a typo in

```
<div class="glide__bullets" data-guide-el="controls[nav]">
```

Should be `data-glide-el`not guide.

Answer (score 2):

After taking a break from this problem and coming back to it, I stumbled on the specific method that does this in glide.js. Once a glide object is created, you can call

```
glide.go('=<slide_number>');
```

where `<slide_number>` is replaced by an integer, e.g. `glide.go('=2')`

Answer (score 1):

I stumpled upon the the same problem. I solved it by nesting the bullets within the track div.

See Example with parts of your Code

```
<div id="slider" class="glide">
        <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
            <div class="glide__slides">
              ......
            </div>
        

        <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
            <button id="slideBack" class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">&lt;</button>
            <button id="slideForward" class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">&gt;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
            <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=0"></button>
            <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=1"></button>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Closing Tag of track -->
    </div>
```